# cannot find module 'axios' after bundling with parcel

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, parceljs

I am building a server side rendered website after i built the api for it.

Now, I am getting this error `cannot find module 'axios'` when importing axios in a js module and bundling it using parcel 2.0.1.
Parcel and axios are both installed as dependencies and axios is installed as a dev dependency as well, and it is in the node modules.

Before I installed parcel and when I imported the js file into the html pug file, axios worked fine (it did the fetching as expected), but only when I tried to bundle it that it started giving me this error.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add `"browserslist": "> 0.5%, last 2 versions, not dead",` to your package.json and it should work.

Here is the documentation from parcel - https://parceljs.org/getting-started/webapp/ and the explaination:

> By default Parcel does not perform any code transpilation. This means that if you write your code using modern language features, that’s what Parcel will output. You can declare your app’s supported browsers using the browserslist field. When this field is declared, Parcel will transpile your code accordingly to ensure compatibility with your supported browsers.

Answer (score 0):

In the closest (from the root of project directory) package.json file, add or update "type" field with a value of "module". It will ensure that all your .js, .ts and .mjs files are interpreted as ES modules.

```
...
{
  ...
  "type": "module"
  ...
}
...
```

Comment: should I add it to the scripts or where exactly, because i tried adding it in the general curly braces and the page does not even load anymore.

Comment: ok, i have done it but now it is asking me to change all my "require" imports to "import"! is there maybe another solution ?

Answer (score 0):

axios should install as dependencies, not dev dependency.please try it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i installed it as a dependency but i still get the same error.